RuntimeException thrown after @Transactional method execution preventing the @Transactional method from committing
I have a non-transactional method calling a transactional method, and then throwing a RuntimeException after the transactional method's execution.
Here is my code structure:
ValidateCodeService:

public void callingMethod(){
   ///some logic
   if (codeReceivedFromUser != codeStoredInDB){
      codeDTO.setNoOfRetries (codeDTO.getNoOfRetries() -1 );
      codeRepository.update(codeDTO);
      throw new RuntimeException(CodeError.CDE1);
   }
}

CodeRepository:
public class CodeRepository extends SuperRepository <Code, Integer>{
@Transactional 
public codeDTO update (codeDTO dto){
     ///some logic
     super.merge(TransformDTOToEntity(dto));
     return dto;
}
}

SuperRepository:
public class SuperRepository{
public void merge(T entity){
     getEm.merge(entity);
     getEm.flush();
}
}

When I check my logs, I can see that the query is flushed but then the error log immediately, without commit:
hibernate flush
[my update query]
log error
[my CodeError.CDE1]
I would like to note that I also call CodeRepository.update from another non-transactional method that does not have error throwing, and the update is committed as expected.
The log for that call looks like this
hibernate flush
[my update query]
hibernate commit
JDBC commit
Question:
Why does the transaction not commit after throwing a RuntimeException in the callingMethod, while it commits successfully in other cases? How can I ensure that my update is committed before the exception is thrown?

This is a strange behavior. I would try to commit the transaction manually by injecting jakarta.transaction.UserTransaction (instead of using the @Transactional annotation).
You could try something like:
  import jakarta.transaction.UserTransaction;

  public class CodeRepository extends SuperRepository <Code, Integer>{
    @Inject
    UserTransaction transaction;

    public codeDTO update (codeDTO dto){
       ///some logic
       try{
         transaction.begin();
         super.merge(TransformDTOToEntity(dto));
         transaction.commit();
       } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return dto;
  }
}


I believe you need to annotate your SuperRepository with @Transactional to continue using the same transaction.
